# What is the intuition for defining the measurable sets in this manner?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I am following a construction of a measure on subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. The idea is to first define the semi-algebra of intervals and a "measure" $\mu$ on this semi-algebra which acts as we expect a length function should. i.e. $\mu(I)=b-a$ for intervals $[a,b)$ (note: the intervals can be open or closed on either side), $\mu(I+x)=\mu(I)$ (length is translation invariant), and $\mu(E)=\sum\mu(E_i)$ where $E_i$ are the disjoint union of $E$. Given this, I can quite easily show that we can extend this to a $\sigma$-additive measure $\nu$, on the algebra generated by this semi-algebra of intervals.

My question is regarding the extension of this $\nu$ to $\pi$ on the $\sigma$-algebra containing this algebra.

The idea as I understand is to first define an outer measure $\pi^*$ on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. An outer measure satisfies the following properties:

> 1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.
> 2. For $E\subseteq F$, $\mu(E)\leq\mu(F)$.
> 3. For $E\subseteq\bigcup E_i$, $\mu(E)\leq\sum\mu(E_i)$

We define $\pi^*(E)$ as $\inf\limits_{\{E_i\}}\nu(E_i)$, where the $E_i$ are elements of the algebra and cover $E$. It is easy to check this is an outer measure.

Here is where I am confused about intutition: The next step is to define a collection of measurable sets $\mathcal{U}$ using this outer measure by stipulating that a set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is measurable if for every $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ $\pi^*(E)=\pi^*(A\cap E)+\pi^*(A^c\cap E)$. I am struggling to understand intuitively why these sets should be the measurable ones? Can anyone elucidate this condition for me?

I understand that from here we can show that this measurable space is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the algebra and that $\pi^*$ on this space extends $\nu$. But I'm struggling with the definition of $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: Briefly (because I don't have time to write a decent answer, and this has probably already been dealt with several times in MSE), one way of getting some intuition about this definition is to note that it can be equivalently formulated as: $E$ is measurable iff $\pi^*(A \cup B) = \pi^*(A) + \pi^*(B)$ whenever $A \subseteq E$ and $B \subseteq {\mathbb R} - E$ (i.e. $\pi^*$ is additive for any two sets that "are separated by $E$"). In considering this, note that $\pi^*$ is always additive on [positively separated sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positively_separated_sets). **(continued)**

Comment: However, $\pi^*$ is not additive on disjoint sets that are sufficiently "intermingled" -- [strong example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/119693/15780). The sets for which $\pi^*$ are additive with respect to are the $\pi^*$-measurable sets (which one can then prove nice things about).

Comment: I happened to return here after taking care of some stuff, saw @Andreas Blass's answer, and realize I probably need to recast the "additivity for sets separated by $E$" from $\mathbb R$ to some (universal) set having positive outer measure. *(moments later)* On second (third?) thought, I think it's fine, since if one of $A$ and/or $B$ has infinite outer measure, then we get equality via $\infty = \infty.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I like to think of the definition of measurability; it may or may not match the historical development of the definition.

Instead of working with the whole real line, let's first deal with a space $Y$ of finite measure, like an interval $[b,c]$. Every subset $A$ of our interval has, as you said, an outer measure $\nu(A)$ obtained by approximating $A$ by supersets whose measure was already known (the sets $E_i$ in your definition of $\nu$).  Symmetrically, one could define the *inner measure* of $A$ by approximating $A$ by subsets whose measure was already known. The inner and outer measures of $A$ are reasonable lower and upper bounds (respectively) for any sensible notion of "measure" of $A$. In particular, if the inner and outer measure of $A$ are the same number, then that number has a good claim to being called the measure of $A$. So one defines the measure of $A$ to be the outer measure of $A$ when that coincides with the inner measure of $A$. (When they don't coincide, we leave the measure of $A$ undefined.)

Using the fact that subsets of $A$ are the same thing as complements of supersets of the complement of $A$, one easily finds that the inner measure of $A$ is given by $\nu(Y)-\nu(A^c)$. So to say that the inner and outer measures of $A$ agree is just to say that $\nu(A)+\nu(A^c)=\nu(Y)$.

That looks somewhat like the definition of measurability that you quoted, but it's not exactly the same, and it's only for the situation of a space $Y$ of finite measure, not something like the whole real line.

So what about the whole real line? When should a set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ be measurable? The first idea that occurs to me is to require $A\cap[n,n+1]$ to be measurable (as a subset of the finite measure space $[n,n+1]$) for all integers $n$. Then we can define (and we want to define, for the sake of $\sigma$-additivity) $\pi(A)$ to be $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\nu(A\cap[n,n+1])$.

The second idea that occurs to me is to require $A\cap[-n,n]$ to be measurable (as a subset of the finite measure space $[-n,n]$) for all natural numbers (or even all positive reals) $n$. Then define $\pi(A)$ to be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu(A\cap[-n,n])$.

Fortunately, these two ideas are equivalent to each other, i.e., they produce the same $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets and the same measure function. The definition you quoted broadens the two ideas by using arbitrary sets $E$ in place of intervals like $[n,n+1]$ or $[-n,n]$, but it too is equivalent to my two ideas.  I personally prefer to think of just the simpler case where $E$ is an interval, but using unrestricted $E$'s makes the definition shorter (and maybe easier to use).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I found your example using the finite measure sets very helpful. Just as a point of clarification, am I correct to assume that you are using $\nu$ to denote the outer measure of a set?

Comment: Yes, that's how I useed $\nu$.