# The additivity of outer measure for disjoint sets, one of these is Borel set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Denote Lebesgue outer measure $\mu^\ast$.

I want to show

if $A,B\subset \mathbb R$ are disjoint and one of these sets is Borel set, then $\mu^\ast(A\cup B)=\mu^\ast(A)+\mu^\ast(B)$ holds. $\cdots \bigstar$

---

I know two facts that

if $A,B\subset \mathbb R$ are disjoint and one of these sets is open, then $\mu^\ast(A\cup B)=\mu^\ast(A)+\mu^\ast(B)$

and

if $A,B\subset \mathbb R$ are disjoint and one of these sets is closed, then $\mu^\ast(A\cup B)=\mu^\ast(A)+\mu^\ast(B)$.

I thinks these facts seem to work for $\bigstar$, but I didn't go well at present.

This is the step for showing that $\mu^\ast$ is a measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal L)$ so I cannot use the additivity of $\mu^\ast.$

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: This continues to hold if you only assume one of the sets is Lebesgue measurable. This can be easily shown using the criterion for measurability that I gave in the first comment to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4483004/13130), a criterion that I believe isn't difficult to prove from the [Carathéodory's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion). Incidentally, you should probably include in your question what definition you're using for "measurable", as there are many different but equivalent definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is proven in Theorem 2.66 of Sheldon Axler's [Measure, Integration and Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf). In addition to the facts you listed, he uses the additional one that for any Borel set $B$, there exists a closed set $F \subset B$ such that $\mu^{*}(B\backslash F) < \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. The latter he proves in Theorem 2.65. In his book $|A|$ denotes the outer measure of $A$. Hope it helps!